# Importing data into Google Map from ArcGIS KML: fields not recognized

Tags: google-maps, gis, google-maps-markers, arcgis, kmz

I have a shapefile with 1500 records that I've converted to a KMZ in ArcGIS, and then imported into Google Maps.  I want to symbolize the markers by a particular field, however, the issue is that Google Maps is not reading in the field names associated with the original GIS data.

When I try to "Style by Data Column", it only presents me with two options, "Name" and "Description".  I had roughly 20 fields in the original data and while these fields are showing up as information associated with each marker, Google Maps is not letting my symbolize by these fields.

I'm reading that when converting to KMZ in ArcGIS:

```
By default, the pop-up display will be composed of all visible fields from the layer.
```

My question is how to retain the field information when importing as KMZ into Google Maps.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How are the fields stored in the KML?  Is it `<ExtendedData>`?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.  QGIS let's you export to KML in a way that retains fields.  Thanks!